# Chrome on Ubuntu running on Virtualbox very slow

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, chromium, virtualbox-networking

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) on Virtualbox 4.2 on Win 7 Host. I'm getting frequent annoying internet issues. I'm using chrome (and previously chromium) and every no and then, the chrome just stop working. It either kills the request or delays it to quite some extent. I have to click refresh sometimes to get the page open.

I have no idea why this is happening. In windows, my internet works flawless.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to clarify some things quickly, I have some experience troubleshooting Chrome on virtualbox. You are using the windows version of chrome inside a windows 7 64 bit virtual machine, correct? I have also had an issue with Chrome reporting that it crashes every time I close it. There is relatively little documentation on using chrome under these circumstances, which is why I switched to firefox under my virtual machines.

You have installed guest additions i assume? Have you tried using a different browser to see if the problem is network related?

Comment: you're right. firefox does obey quiet well.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a 3 year old question, but I think the issue itself still exists in certain scenarios.

In my case, I had this exact same issue (by the sound of if anyway), and I fixed it by disabling IPv6 inside of the VM.  After that, everything was back to normal.